# criteria query ORDER BY yields error. Is this an SQL-SERVER limitation? How could I order by correctly on a complicated criteria query?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have the following criteria query:

```
    String cat = "H";
    Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass()).
            add(Restrictions.ne("category", cat)).
            createAlias("employees", "emp").
            createAlias("emp.company", "company");
    Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
    for(Region r: regions){
           disjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("company.region", r));
    }
    criteria.add(disjunction);

    if(status != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", status));
    }

    if (period != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("period", period));
    }

    criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("id")) //this line was added to try to "fix" the error, but it still happened.
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
```

I guess a query that explains my criteria query could be:

```
  select n.* from NOMINATION n
  join NOMINEE i on n.NOM_ID = i.NOM_ID
  join EMPLOYEE e on e.EMP_ID = i.EMP_ID
  join COMPANY c on c.COMPANY_CODE = e.COMPANY_CODE
  where n.CATEGORY_CODE!='H' and (c.REGION_ID = ? or c.REGION_ID = ? or c.REGION_ID = ?) and n.STATUS_ID = ? and n.PERIOD_ID = ?
  order by n.NOM_ID
```

What I am trying to do here, is pretty confusing but for the most part it works except when I add this specific line (though the query works fine):

```
 criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
```

and then I get error:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Column "NOMINATION.NOM_ID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Which I suspect is something that has to do with SQL-SERVER. I am already grouping by `id`. So what am I doing wrong here, or should I just use HQL?

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't have any `goup by` clause. So why are you using a `groupProperty()`? In fact, your SQL query doesn't have any projection (it select N.*), so you don't need any projection in your criteria query.

Comment: indeed it doesn't but I was under the impression that the property had to be added to an aggregate or to the select clause in order to work... needless to say the first time I tried my example I didn't have any `groupProperty()` just the one `addOrder()` and it still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query seems to be a simple Query which doesn't have any group function used or not a group by query. According to your current requirements you do not have to use this line.

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("id")).addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
```

Or you have to modify your  sql statements.

Comment: Sorry that's not it. I added the projection due to the error, so perhaps I should edit that.

Comment: Why you are using Disjunction ?

Comment: for the group of ORs in the sql-query example... it's not a set list so I cannot add a specific number of ORs like i did in the example

Comment: I suppose you already know it is use to Group expressions together in a single disjunction. Which means you are using Aggregate function and  the column id is not used in your disjunction method. So you have to make your id part of disjunction to it work.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting - I didn't know the disjunction was an aggregate. So how do you suggest I add the id to the disjunction? Or is there a way for me to do the for-loop of ORs in a different manner than disjunctions?

Comment: The order by has no impact here. Because aggregate functions goes from row to row so In your situation currently order by id is not a available option so you should use this query as sub query and use main query for order by.

Comment: Ok I will try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: you have an other option If your query is complex and you only have to sort it with id then use java comparator for simply sorting your result list with id.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the disjunction thing, but it appears disjunction wasn't at fault. It was my wrapper pagination class that had aggregate function of `count()`. It wasn't the reason, but still helped me out.